# jQuery populate dynamic created select box from another select

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, each

I have a form where you can dynamically add new rows via jQuery. It creates the elements fine. However, I have a select box on the new row. When it is created, it is empty. I need to populate it from the first select box of that type (class).

Here is the HTML...

```
<select class="cyclePoSelect" name="poNumber[]" style="WIDTH: 100px">
  <option value="0" selected="">Select One</option>
  <option value="VE-13475">VE-13475</option>
  <option value="VZ-61300">VZ-61300</option>
</select>

<select class="cyclePoSelect" name="poNumber[]" style="WIDTH: 100px">
  <option value="0" selected="">Select One</option>
  <option value="VE-13475">VE-13475</option>
  <option value="VZ-61300">VZ-61300</option>
</select>

<!-- This is the dynamically created element -->
<select class="cyclePoSelect" name="poNumber[]" style="WIDTH: 100px">
  <option value="0" selected="">Select One</option>      
</select>
```

I need to add the 2 options from the first select to the last select. Adding them should be no problem. But I can't seem to get a list of options from just the first select box. So far, I have tried...

```
$(".cyclePoSelect > option:first").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

That just gives me the "Select One" option.

```
$(".cyclePoSelect > option").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

That gives me all options, but from BOTH existing select boxes.

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/scott80109/tkok9vwy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".cyclePoSelect:last").html($(".cyclePoSelect:first").html())
```

Comment: Great job! I hate when I over think things.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".cyclePoSelect:last").html($(".cyclePoSelect:eq(0)").html());
```

**Reference:**

- [**:last**](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)
- [**:eq**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)