# Populate an html list with index of another html list in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list, indexing, each

See the diagram attached. In jquery, how can i generate the small numbers in red in list B? The small numbers in red (2,3,8) represent the index position of the list elements that have a blue background in list A.

How can I extract the indexes of blue boxes in list **A** and add them in the small boxes in list **B** using Jquery? Any Hints?

[image]

*Script*

```
var wrapper = $('.orig-list li');
wrapper.each(function() {
    wrapper.text(newStr);
    for(var i = 0; i< wrapper.length; i++) {
        $('.index').each(function(){
            $(this).text(wrapper.index(i));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: your question looks like a repost of another you posted http://stackoverflow.com/q/41160449/1415724 that contained "some" code, but no HTML for it. Your question here contains no code at all. I'm sure there'd be a lot of hits on Google for this, I am 100% certain of it.

Comment: Here's one that was under "Related" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449569/jquery-populate-dynamic-created-select-box-from-another-select btw, and is most likely a duplicate.

Comment: It is a repost, and I repost because no one answered cus I think no one understood, if there are any hints on google please help me find

Comment: You need to share the HTML and your attempted script

Comment: no one answered probably because they didn't know "how" to answer, given you left out a lot of relevant code and you didn't do that there and you didn't do that here. So put yourself in their shoes and you'll see what I mean. The less the people know, the less chances you get for a solution and the more time it takes. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) to get the matching element in original list and use [`.index(element)][2]` to get the matched element index.

```
var origList = $('.orig-list li')
$('.next-list li').each(function(i) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var matchingElement = origList.filter(function() {
        return text == $(this).text()
    });
    if (matchingElement.length) {
        $(this).text(text + " " + origList.index(matchingElement));
        matchingElement.addClass('high')
    }
});
```

**Note 1:** In the example I have used *exact* match condition. I would recommed you to use `data-*` custom attribute to estabhish relationship between `li` element of these list.

**Note 2:** Index starts with 0.

```js
var origList = $('.orig-list li')
$('.next-list li').each(function(i) {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var matchingElement = origList.filter(function() {
    return text == $(this).text()
  });
  if (matchingElement.length) {
    $(this).text(text + " " + origList.index(matchingElement));
    matchingElement.addClass('high')
  }
});
```

```css
.high {
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="orig-list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>L</li>
</ul>

<ul class="next-list">
  <li>L</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>F</li>  
</ul>
```